# Azure Media Player in Blazor

Tags: azure, razor, blazor, azure-media-services, azure-media-player

I was trying to get the Azure Media Player running in Blazor - no success. 
Everything works fine in an Asp.net core project.

In Blazor its always the normal Html player.
Tried it with diffrent browsers - always the same.

It must have something to do with the js not get loaded correctly.

Does anybody has an idea?

Here is an example where i put the script and style:
https://blazorfiddle.com/s/bhos6ocq

Comment: Well, your link with the media file works on my machine: Win10 in Edge and Chrome

Comment: can you play the video? is the player an azure media player? for me its the normal html player and i cannot play the video. In Edge i can play the video, but its not the Azure Media Player.

Answer (score 0):

try to use the **HLS(v4)** url with **m3u8** format, then use this library to display it with the html video tag : https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js